# How to capture internet ip change event in windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a Air-Tell Brod-band connection in my office.

Every time when we restarts router then internet ip got changed.

I have an web application in asp.net with ip restriction.

For that application I've made a windows service that updates internet ip on my data-base records.

Can any one tell me how can i capture internet ip change event in windows service.

So that when ever we restarts router, service will automatically update record of ip on database.

Comment: Maybe this is usefull: [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9477187/1108036)

Comment: this post may be helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/515436/how-to-get-internet-ip

Comment: I'm able in find my systems internet IP.
I just need to know that is there any event that captures ip change.

Answer (score 0):

You could use http://www.whatismyip.com/ and parse the html for the ip address.

You might set up a timer or thread that periodically checks this page or a list of pages like this for the address to detect the change.